# Finite Simplicial Complexes: Show that open sets have open connected subsets containing any point

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

**The question:**

I am required to show the following: Let $K$ be a finite simplicial complex, let $x \in |K|$ and suppose that $U$ is an open set containing $x$. Then there is an open connected set $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$.

**My attempt:**

Let $D$ be the disjoint union of simplices from which $|K|$ is obtained, and let $q:D \to |K|$ be the quotient map.

$q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $D$, by definition of quotient spaces.

We take it as standard that the restriction of $q$ to the insides of the simplices in $D$ is a bijection, so there is exactly one simplex $\sigma$ in $D$ such that $x \in q($inside$(\sigma))$.

Then there is some $\overline{x}$ in $\sigma$ such that $q(\overline{x}) = x$.

$\overline{x} \in q^{-1}(U) \cap ($inside$(\sigma))$, which is an open subset of inside$(\sigma)$, and hence is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. Thus, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(\overline{x},\epsilon) \subseteq q^{-1}(U) \cap ($inside$(\sigma))$.

$B(\overline{x}, \epsilon)$ is connected, open in $D$, and contains $\overline{x}$.

Thus, $q(B(\overline{x}, \epsilon))$ is connected (by the continuity of $q$), open in $|K|$ (by definition of a quotient space), and contains $x$. So it is the desired $V$.

**Concerns:**

I feel as if I'm overcomplicating this hugely - I struggle to know what I'm "allowed" to assume as intuitively clear in this topic.

I'm also not sure that the argument I'm using even works, as it relies on jumping around a lot of different topologies and it's possible that I'm making unwarranted assumptions.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but isn't this just because any space is the union of its connected components? For $V$ couldn't you take the connected component of $U$ that contains $x$? It seems like the "finite simplicial complex" assumption isn't needed.

Comment: @William connected components aren't necessarily open, unless there are finitely many of them, so I don't think you can just use that. If you could show that there can only be finitely many connected components, then it would work, but I don't think you can do that, as you could make your open set out of infinitely many open balls of radius say $2^{-n}$.